# Guardar los valores de múltiples checkbox en un solo campo de un tabla

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, json

Tengo una tabla con múltiples checkbox, en el js realizo el procesamiento de los datos:

```js
    $("#btn_plan").click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/vistas/recursos/recurso_fileinput.php?opt=NuevaPlaneacion",
        data: {
          'check_cognitivo_plan': JSON.stringify($('[name="check_cognitivo[]"]').serializeArray())
        }
      }).done(function(res) {
        alert(res);
      });
    });
```

```html
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check_cognitivo[]" value="Recordar">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check1">Recordar</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check_cognitivo[]" value="Comprender">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check2">Comprender</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="check_cognitivo[]" value="Aplicar">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check3">Aplicar</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check4" name="check_cognitivo[]" value="Analizar">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check4">Analizar</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check5" name="check_cognitivo[]" value="Evaluar">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check5">Evaluar</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check6" name="check_cognitivo[]" value="Crear">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check6">Crear</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-warning pull-left" id="btn_plan" name="action" value="add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span> Guardar</button>
```

y el envío de los datos lo realizo así:

```php
public function registrar_planeador($Id_Docente,$Id_Area,$Id_Grado,$Nivel_Cognitivo,$Obj_Aprendizaje,$date){
                $conectar=parent::conexion();
                parent::set_names();

    $CheckCognitivo = print_r(json_decode($_POST["check_cognitivo_plan"],TRUE));
    foreach ($CheckCognitivo as $value) {
       $cognicion = $cognicion.' '.$value;
     }
     $sql="insert into tabla_palneador 
                values(null,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
                $sql=$conectar->prepare($sql);
                $sql->bindValue(1, $_POST["NameDocente"]);
                $sql->bindValue(2, $_POST["NameAsignatura"]);
                $sql->bindValue(3, $_POST["GradoPlaneador"]);
                $sql->bindValue(4, $cognicion);                        
                $sql->execute();

              }
```

Cuando realizo el envío de los datos en el `alert` se carga toda la data y los valores de los `checkbox` como un array; trato de convertirlo a `string` con el `foreach` pero no lo consigo. ¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

Answer (score 0):

no estoy seguro de la parte de usar siempre el mismo name para todos los check, pero se me ocurre capturar los datos del formulario por js en lugar de usar el post, podes capturar todos los elementos

```js
const submit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
 let checkboxes = [...document.getElementsByTagName("input")].map(check => {
    if (check.name === "check_cognitivo[]")
        {
          return {[check.value]: check.checked}
        }
      }
    )
  console.log(checkboxes)
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check_cognitivo[]" value="Recordar">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check1">Recordar</label>
        </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check_cognitivo[]" value="Comprender">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check2">Comprender</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="check_cognitivo[]" value="Aplicar">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check3">Aplicar</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check4" name="check_cognitivo[]" value="Analizar">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check4">Analizar</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check5" name="check_cognitivo[]" value="Evaluar">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check5">Evaluar</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check6" name="check_cognitivo[]" value="Crear">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check6">Crear</label>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-default btn-warning pull-left" id="btn_plan" name="action" value="add" onclick="submit(event)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span> Guardar</button>
```

ahi los valores los podes devolver como gustes.

Comment: Facundo gracias por su pronta respuesta, utilizando neme diferente para cada checkbox si funciona, el problema es que agrupa todos los checkbox del formulario en un solo string y requiero que vayan separados de acuerdo a la categoría que les corresponde y tengo 5 categorías diferentes por eso debo hacerlo con el mismo name de acuerdo a esa categoría

Comment: claro, el map que escribi, podes formatear los datos como creas conveniente. por el ejemplo, devuelve un array de objetos, con los valores, pero lo podes componer como un string o como necesites.